How do you make a frame smaller than 1?
I have an app in which you're supposed to get coordinates from Google maps by moving the map to the coordinates and pressing next. In order to show where the map is pointing there's a black rectangle in the middle, which I need to turn into a small dot.
Originally the frame was a black rectangle with width and height set to 8. So I made it red, set the WidthRequest and HeightRequest to 1, and gave it a radius like so
<Frame 
    BackgroundColor="Red"
    Opacity="1"
    WidthRequest="0.01"
    HeightRequest="0.01"
    CornerRadius="20"   
    InputTransparent="True"
    HorizontalOptions="Center"
    VerticalOptions="Center" 
/>

Which gives this circle:

Which isn't exactly a small circle. Setting the Width and Height requests to less than 1 gives them the same size as 1, even though they're double.
The full code is this. I didn't make it, and if there are better ways to do this I am open to suggestions
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:ctrl="clr-namespace:DriverReporting.CustomControls"
    xmlns:maps="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps"
    x:Class="DriverReporting.Views.ManualMapPage"
    Title="{Binding DisplayedValue}">
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="Næste" Command="{Binding CommitCommand}" />
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <Grid HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ctrl:MapControl
            Grid.RowSpan="2" x:Name="MapControl"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            CameraPosition="{Binding Value}"
            InitialPosition="{Binding InitialLocation}"
         />

        <Frame 
            BackgroundColor="Red"
            Opacity="1"
            WidthRequest="0.01"
            HeightRequest="0.01"
            CornerRadius="20"   
            InputTransparent="True"
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
        />
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>


Why are you using CornerRadius 20?

It needs to be a circle. Isn't that how you make a circle?

You want a 1 pixel circle?

Well I've been asked to have a small circle. So yeah I guess a bit bigger than that, but smaller than in the picture

Then use a smaller CornerRadius

I tried and it became a square

Turns out all I needed was a BoxView instead of a Frame
<BoxView 
    WidthRequest="10"
    HeightRequest="10"
    Color="Red"
    CornerRadius="5"
    HorizontalOptions="Center"
    VerticalOptions="Center"
/>

